# Portable Google Desktop Search index

Tags: windows, search, desktop-search, google-desktop-search

- I have a huge number of documents and articles indexed using Google Desktop
- I sync these data constantly to my USB flash drive
- I mount my USB flash drive on my other PC (slow with limited storage) so that these documents appear at the same path as it was seen on my first PC.
- I don't want to install Google Desktop on my other PC because I don't want it to perform indexing processes and because the index takes a lot of space
- I need to be able to search these data on my other PC
- My question is: **How to make Google Desktop index files portable and use them in another PC?**
- If the solution is to use a third party client to Google Desktop indexes, I prefer it to be open source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing Google Desktop (which is a resource hog on any system) on both boxes with Locate32 (http://www.locate32.net/). It creates a database of all files on your computer, database updates are fairly quick, searches are almost instantaneous, and it supports "regular expression" searches.

I even use it in an XP VM to point to multiple server shares.

Comment: Latest version released 2007 this means it is not under active development

Comment: 1. The developer posted a comment back in May, 2010, explaining how to submit bugs and feature requests. That doesn't sound like "not under active development" to me.
2. Who cares if the software hasn't been updated since 2007? It works great, is super fast, has a minimal performance hit, and already supports advanced features like regular expressions and 64 bit OS's.
3. It's a file search tool, for gosh sakes; it's not an office suite.

Comment: I just don't see how it answers the OP. Locate32 does not index file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can "move" the index location of Google Desktop Search by a registry key hack:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Google Desktop]
"data_dir"="D:\\MyIndex\\Google Desktop\\d1f5397c787a"
```

Once the indexing was done, end the process "GoogleDesktop.exe" and move the folder to the location you wish and edit the above registry key to point to the new location.